# How To Kill Process With Minimum Processor Consumption

Tags: python, kill-process, psutil

I was looking for a python script to kill particular running process(s). I got a script to get list of all currently running processes. So I did some modifications and it works as follows:

A list named `blackList` stores all the unwanted processes which needs to be killed. The script iterates through fetched process names and compares with the blackList's content. If it matches, then that process is terminated.

**Code:**

```
import psutil

blackList = ["SkypeHost.exe", "Music.UI.exe", "SearchUI.exe", "Video.UI.exe", "backgroundTaskHost.exe"]

while True:
  for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    try:
        pinfo = proc.as_dict(attrs=['pid', 'name', 'username'])
    except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
        pass
    else:
        for i in blackList:
            if pinfo["name"] == i:
                proc.kill()
```

The script works fine but its consuming much of my processor.

**Without running the script**

[Without running the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKJJQ.png)

**While Script is running**

[While Script is running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dLoR.png)

Is there any way to minimize this consumption? Why is it consuming so much of processor?

My processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz

Comment: You are running an unconstrained loop, this will run as a fast as it can. You can choose to slow it down with `time.sleep(s)` inside the `while` loop, which would drastically reduce its CPU usage. Alternatively, look for some other event-based approach.

Comment: I suppose, you want to spawn this process as a daemon?

Comment: You were running an unindented loop, I fixed that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import time
```

and throw a `time.sleep(some small time frame)` in your loop.

Doing `while True` with no break is going to thrash your cpu.

Comment: Delay of 1 second reduces the consumption. Thank You